# Logging CPU performance & memory usage data

Tags: memory-usage

How do I direct ( to a csv file for example) tabulated data for the amount of memory used with respect to run-time for a given command I have executed in the terminal?

Or another way to put it, does there exist a Linux package that pretty much the same as task manager in windows?

Comment: You could look at the sysstat suite of tools..

Comment: ok thanks @doug I'll delete this question I should have just asked in the chat rooms